# Does the value of one cell exist in another column from a different spreadsheet?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Here in [this first sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bTOgJaXXBYsyj5Y4Jynby6BMvy5Ig5v-CdvY9ZA9HZY/edit#gid=185058844), I want to know whether the value from one cell (i.e. E3) exists within a column (K:K) within another google sheet. (And then I want to know the same for the entire column)

You'll see where I've approximated a formula that explains what I want in T3, but I don't know what I really need it to say. I have the html code from the other sheet there, like you'd do in an import range, with the tab and range, but can you help form the formula, or am I just totally on the wrong track?

(this is the [second sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KwxGR5-0AzmQBgTRL2i0saY_4cvlWjjCtz67YjzRD8A/edit#gid=273510336) that it's looking in)

Comment: As Player()'s answer shows, the key function you're looking for is `ImportRange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(E3:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1KwxGR5-0AzmQBgTRL2i0saY_4cvlWjjCtz67YjzRD8A", 
 "WI ECE Content Alignment!K2:K"))), "Y", ))
```

[image]